# How to transfer parameter to Paypal and get back it after going to success page?

Tags: api, paypal

I need some help with my issue.

I created the requirement payment button and want to transfer some token in submitting form and get it back on success page in query string for example.

Is it possible ?

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `custom` variable with PDT: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/